# How to add a before_filter in UserMailer which checks if it is OK to mail a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

is there a global way I can write a before_filter for my user mailer, that checks to see if the user has emails disabled? Right now every mailer I have checks the user's setting, this is very redundant. I would like to DRY this up by having a before_filter that works for all mailers.

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

 before_filter :check_if_we_can_mail_the_user

 ....

 private

   def check_if_we_can_mail_the_user
     if current_user.mail_me == true
       #continue
     else
      Do something to stop the controller from continuing to mail out
     end
   end
 end
```

Possible? Has anyone done something like this? Thanks

Comment: there is no such thing, because you would normally put this kind of logic into fe. the user-model. the other problem is, that in a lot of cases you send mails asynchrounus and don't have a thing like 'current_user'

Answer (score 34):

Rails 4 already has before_filter and after_filter callbacks. For Rails 3 users, it's surprisingly simple to add them: just include AbstractController::Callbacks. This mimics the [change to Rails 4](https://github.com/jsl/rails/commit/4f28c4fc9a51bbab76d5dcde033c47aa6711339b) which apart from comments and tests, just included Callbacks.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :check_email

  def some_mail_action(user)
    @user = user
    ...
  end

  private
  def check_email
    if @user.email.nil?
      mail.perform_deliveries = false
    end
    true
  end

end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "before_filter"? Why "after"?

Comment: we don't have the `@user` variable in the before_filter! and the mail is not yet delivered.

Comment: @Kulgar the docs actually explain that you can use both, but if you use after_filter you can make logic that depends on instance variables set on the mailer method: "You could use a before_action to populate the mail object with defaults, delivery_method_options or insert default headers and attachments.

You could use an after_action to do similar setup as a before_action but using instance variables set in your mailer action." (Source: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks)

Comment: Thanks @sandre89 :)

Answer (score 6):

I haven't done this, but I've done similar things with an email interceptor.

```
class MailInterceptor    
    def self.delivering_email(message)
        if User.where( :email => message.to ).first.mail_me != true
            message.perform_deliveries = false
        end
    end
end
```

You won't have access current_user, so you find the user by email, which should already be in the mail object as the 'to' field.

There's a good Railscast covering setting up email interceptors.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3?view=asciicast

Answer (score 1):

I edited @naudster 's answer to get the information from message

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :check_email

  private
  def check_email
    if message.to.nil?
      message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out https://github.com/kelyar/mailer_callbacks.  It looks like it will do what you want.

Comment: For the modern reader: Rails 4 now has mailer callbacks: before_action, after_action, around_action http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks