# ActionMailer after_filter breaking content_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

[Rails 3.2.13] I have a mailer that sends out implicit multipart emails based on `.text.erb` and `.html.haml` templates.  No problems there.

I'm trying to add an after_filter to conditionally prevent sending to invalid emails.  Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709805) and all documentation I've read, this seems pretty straightforward.

However, including this after_filter changes content type from `multipart/alternative` to `text/plain`, **even if the email is valid**.  In the docs: 'Implicit template rendering is not performed if any attachments or parts have been added to the email'.  Does that apply here?  Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

Banging my head against the wall, because this seems so straightforward.

```
class Notify < ActionMailer::Base

  include AbstractController::Callbacks

  after_filter :ensure_valid

  def some_email(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    mail(to: @user.email)
  end

  ...

  private

  def ensure_valid
    if User.where(email: mail.to, invalid_email: true).any?
      mail.perform_deliveries = false
    end
    true
  end

end
```

**Edit**: after more tinkering, it seems calling the `mail` object **at all** in the after_filter turns off multipart, even with something like:

```
def ensure_valid
  puts "mail: #{mail}"
  true
end
```

What's going on here?

---

Tried adding content_type + params back manually in the after_filter, e.g.

```
mail.content_type = 'multipart/alternative'
mail.header['Content-Type'].parameters[:boundary] = mail.body.boundary
mail.header['Content-Type'].parameters[:charset] = 'UTF-8'
```

But for whatever reason this doesn't seem to be working.  It DOES set content_type if I only include

```
mail.content_type = 'multipart/alternative'
```

.. but then I'm missing boundary and charset parameters.

Other things I've tried that don't work:

- setting default content_type in environment.rb
- setting default content_type in the mailer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not entirely sure what's going on here, but it seems using the `message` object instead of `mail` in the after_filter fixes this:

```
def ensure_valid
  if User.where(email: message.to, invalid_email: true).any?
    message.perform_deliveries = false
  end
  true
end
```

This sets `perform_deliveries` correctly without affecting the content_type (leaves it as `multipart/alternative`).  Strange that all examples used the `mail` object instead of `message`.