# How to set global variable in mailer, depend on parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My mailer looks like this:

```
class RenovationOrderMailer < ApplicationMailer

 default from: "example@gmail.com"

  def customer_confirmation(renovation_order)
    @renovation_order = renovation_order
    mail(to: "example123@gmail.com", subject: 'We confirm!')
  end

  def order_summary(renovation_order)
    @renovation_order = renovation_order
    mail(to: "example234@gmail.com", subject: 'You have new order!')
  end

  def custom_email(renovation_order)
    @renovation_order = renovation_order
    mail(to: "example345@gmail.com", subject: 'Info about order')
  end

  def custom_email_confirmation(renovation_order)
    @renovation_order = renovation_order
    mail(to: "example456@gmail.com", subject: 'You sended info')
  end

end
```

As you can see in every method I declare `@renovation_order` variable which I need in method view. Is there a solution to declare this variable once, and have access to it in every method in mailer?

I know there is toppic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18709805/2502605, but there is nothing about creating shared view variables, passing data do mailer before_action and syntax for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a before\_filter in UserMailer which checks if it is OK to mail a user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594626/how-to-add-a-before-filter-in-usermailer-which-checks-if-it-is-ok-to-mail-a-user)

Answer (score 1):

Before Action will do the magic

```
before_action { @renovation_order = "example123@gmail.com"}
```

check this for more documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Just look at this answer: [How to add a before_filter in UserMailer which checks if it is OK to mail a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594626/how-to-add-a-before-filter-in-usermailer-which-checks-if-it-is-ok-to-mail-a-user/18709805#18709805).

I don't know how to mark as duplicate.

Comment: I readed before that post, there is no clear cleues about syntax and before_action

Comment: @Outside_Box read that answer's comments. It should be after_filter not before_filter

Comment: I read it carefully and still in my opinion this question isn`t duplicate:)